# search.php will stack and show multiple times

Tags: php

my site is a search engine and and if you type in search.php with the forward slashes it will show results the same as the regular url. for example:

regular url:
http://domain.com/search.php?query=keyword&select=all

stacking url:
http://domain.com/search.php/search.php?query=keyword&select=all
http://domain.com/search.php/search.php/search.php?query=keyword&select=all

I can literally keep adding search.php/ and it will always work.
How can I make it only work when the regular url is used? .htaccess maybe?
Another thing is my search.php is in the root directory and not in a "search" subfolder. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
Also if anyone else ever sees this and is having the same problem. I added AcceptPathInfo Off to my .htaccess and it seemed to fix it.

Comment: I'm confused, why does it stack? how are you redirecting? What is the action of your form ?

Comment: Another question is: Why? As long as you dont use the links nobody will realize it. For example its the same on facebook ;)

Comment: @Khez: Its not stacking itself, chris stacks the urls together and is wondering, why it works (or I really dont understand the question :D). It works, because the webserver realize, that `/search.php` is a valid file and stops resolving.

Comment: ... anything after ? is called a Query String and it can be anything, even include another url or several...

Comment: The reason I was worried is because google sends very little traffic to site with the stacking "thats how I realised the problem". I guess its not that big if a deal but it kinda bothered me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 'stacking' as such, but PATH_INFO is coming into play. /search.php/anything-you like will execute search.php, and pass anything-you-like as the PATH_INFO value. Take a look at [disabling it in apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo).

Alternatively, you could redirect search.php if it has a non-null value for $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

If you're accessing /search.php/ and your form submits to "search.php", I believe you'll see this behaviour. You should probably change the form's action to /search.php, if this is the cause.

Comment: Sounds like this could be the problem. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: it seems to be the PATH_INFO. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in you search box remove the search.php